# How to remove PluginSettings after plugin uninstallation in Bitbucket?

Tags: plugins, bitbucket, settings, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I created custom plugin for bitbucket server, and i want to store some per repository data. After reading docs i choose to use PluginSettings. But after I delete the plugin and install a new version, the settings are saved, but I need them to be cleared. How to do it?